# LeetCode LinkedList | Floyd's Cycle-Finding algorithm or Hare-Tortoise algorithm Code not working

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I am peacefully trying to code to solve [LeetCode - Linked List Cycle II](https://leetcode.com/problems/linked-list-cycle-ii/description/)

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) {
 *         val = x;
 *         next = null;
 *     }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public ListNode detectCycle(ListNode head) {
        var slow = head;
        var fast = head;
        while(slow!=fast){
            if(fast==null || fast.next==null){
                return null;
            }
            slow=slow.next;
            fast=fast.next.next;
        }
        var whereIsCollision = head;
        while(whereIsCollision!=slow){
            whereIsCollision=whereIsCollision.next;
            slow=slow.next;
        }
        return whereIsCollision;
    }
}
```

but it's not working.

return statement -> whereIsCollision which is pointing head is simply returning head only at every run case. Neither if statement working inside first while loop.

Comment: It is clear that you haven't used a debugger. Any reason?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the starting condition as (slow != fast) since initially both pointers are at head so the loop won't even execute to begin with. Use this instead:

```
while(fast && fast.next) {
    slow = slow.next;
    fast = fast.next.next;
    if(slow == fast) {
        slow = head;
        while(slow != fast) {
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next;
        }
        return slow;
    }
}
```